# Angular Form validation From date should be Gretaer than To Date

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I created a small Reactive Form Validation
The form validation is working properly, but when i changed `fromDate` and after that i change `toDate` the time validation doesn't work.

If i do it in the reverse order the validation works.

Here i added my Stackblitz, please help me, how can i overcome this issue[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-guxktk)

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a group for dates and a validator for it. The form will look like:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        FirstName: ['', Validators.required],
        LastName: ['', Validators.required],
        datesGroup: this.formBuilder.group({
            filterFrom: ['', [Validators.required]],
            filterTo: ['', [Validators.required]]
        }, {
            validators: [
                formvalidation.datesValidator('filterFrom', 'filterTo')
            ]
        })
    });
```

And your validator could be as simple as:

```
static datesValidator(field1: string, field2: string) {
    return (group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
        const c1 = group.controls[field1];
        const c2 = group.controls[field2];
        if (c1.value >= c2.value) {
            return {invalidPeriod: true}
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is related to the way that you use the custom time validator. The thing that happens is that you are tring to validate the `fromDate` before you have `toDate` value

So your form looks like so:

```
    this._formGroup = this._formbuilder.group({
      FirstName: ["", [Validators.required]],
      LastName: ["", [Validators.required]],
      _gender: ["1", [Validators.required]],
      _dob: ["", [Validators.required]],
      _fromDate: ["", [Validators.required, formvalidation.comparedate]],
      _ToDate: ["", [Validators.required, formvalidation.comparedate]]
    });
```

And your custom validator looks like so

```
  static comparedate(control: AbstractControl) {
    if (control.parent) {
      let _fromDate = (<FormGroup>control.parent).get("_fromDate").value;
      let _netDate = (<FormGroup>control.parent).get("_ToDate").value;
      if (_fromDate <= _netDate) {
        (<FormGroup>control.parent).get("_fromDate").clearValidators;
        (<FormGroup>control.parent).get("_ToDate").clearValidators;
        return null;
      } else {
        return { Datecompare: null };
      }
    }
```

The thing that happens is that when you validate `_formDate` for the first time you are validating it's value with an empty string and append error to the control.

After that when you input value in the `_toDate` even if the dates are valid you remove the `DateCompare` error from the current control or append it to the current control if the values are not valid. In both cases (error/no-error) you are not clearing the error from the `_fromDate` control, which leaves you form in invalid state until you make changes to the _formDate.

Also the usage of `clearValidators` is kind of wrong, `clearValidators` is a method/function so you have to call it `clearValidators()`, but then even if you use the method correctly and remove the validators, if the user makes further changes to the form there will be no date validation

My suggestion for your issues is the following

```
  static comparedate(control: AbstractControl) {
    if (control.parent) {
      let _fromDate = (<FormGroup>control.parent).get("_fromDate").value;
      let _toDate = (<FormGroup>control.parent).get("_toDate").value;

      if (_fromDate && _toDate) {
        if (_fromDate >= _toDate) {
          control.parent.get("_toDate").setErrors({ Datecompare: true });
          control.parent.get("_fromDate").setErrors({ Datecompare: true });
          return { Datecompare: true };
        }
        control.parent.get("_toDate").setErrors(null);
        control.parent.get("_fromDate").setErrors(null);
        return null;
      }

      return null;
    }
  }
```

So in this validator first i check if both controls have values at all, and if they have value then i check if the `Datecompare` error should be appened. In the cases where the validation is valid (_formDate < _toDate) im removing the errors from both `_toDate` and `_fromDate` controls

Here is a working [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-comparer-stack-overflow?file=src/app/customeValidation.ts)